# Android GridView select an image

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a `GridView` that is set with images. What I want to do is when the user selects (an image) it should show a mark on the image that was selected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

The code in the link can bbe helpful,  I can see two possible solutions

1) If the images are not coming server, you can have two sets of images, one normal and another checked one which appears on clicking .

2)I am not sure if this works, but we can design a custom layout as how we do for the listView and inflate it with the inflater class inside the getview() overrriden method.

Will try the second option and get back to you.

Comment: Maybe I can use onDraw?
I have no idea how to use it can you help me?